# Is there any merit to the Apollo 13 (movie) statement "a computer that can hold millions of pieces of information"?

Tags: apollo-program, myth-busting

Early in [the *Apollo 13* movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112384/), Lovell (Tom Hanks) is showing off the Saturn V and states that a part of what has made the moon landings possible is a belief that anything is possible, "things like a computer that can fit into a single room, and hold millions of pieces of information".

According to Wikipedia's article on [core rope memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_rope_memory) and the article on the [Apollo Guidance Computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Guidance_Computer), the Block II AGC had a total storage (ROM plus RAM) of 40,960 16-bit words, or in modern terms 81,920 bytes. (We sent people to the moon with less computer code than is needed on my system to *list files in a directory!*)

Is there any merit to the statement that the spacecraft computer could hold "millions of pieces of information", or is it simply an attempt at setting the date for when the events took place?

Comment: The apollo computers (there was one on the capsule and one on the LEM) were wonders of computing for their time as much for their software as their hardware. The developers were able to cram an enormous amount of functionality in considering they has so little power and memory to work with.

Comment: @GdD You're getting no argument from me there! And of course, don't discount [the LVDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_Launch_Vehicle_Digital_Computer) either.

Comment: It's also kind of unimpressive, even by 1960s standards, to fit millions of pieces of information in a single room.  A few ordinary phone books probably contain over a million listings.  A million printed pages of ordinary paper can fit in a large closet.

Comment: "Millions of pieces of information" probably refers to bytes.  It's an ironic assertion for those who understand what it means, because today's computers can handle many orders of magnitude more information than that. "A computer that fit into a single room" almost certainly didn't refer to the Apollo Guidance Computer, but to the larger ground computers that supported the mission.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> "things like a computer that can fit into a single room, and hold
>   millions of pieces of information"

was not about the Apollo computer, but about the general-purpose computers that were available around the start of the Apollo program.

In 1960, the [IBM 7090](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_7090) could store 32 kB. In 1964, [IBM introduced the System/360](http://www-03.ibm.com/ibm/history/exhibits/mainframe/mainframe_PR360.html), which could store up to 8 MB of data.

Comment: Good point. Now that you mention it, indeed there is no direct reference to that being about the *onboard* computers.

Comment: Also, for that matter, the reference was to the belief and not to the computers themselves.

Comment: IBM System/360 was also used to execute the simulations for the Apollo program, so it quite directly helped accomplish the moon landings.

Comment: And the IMS database system was developed to manage the bill of materials for the Saturn V and the spacecraft.

Comment: That's 8 million bytes- the number of piece of useful information is going to be a whole  lot smaller than that.

Comment: The spirit of the statement was to describe the sense of optimism prevailing in the early '60s. Not a technically precise statement.

Comment: @user2617804 Actually to the contrary; in early computers, making efficient use of the space (both persistent storage as well as various forms of working memory) was a prime consideration. Broadly speaking, for most computers that we think of as such (excluding for example embedded systems), this lasted into the second half of the 1990s.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Even the most efficient use of space cannot reduce every relevant piece of information to a single byte. *Piece of information* of course is very imprecise, but I think one can safely say, at the least, that anything that can have more than 255 distinct and meaningful values cannot be encoded in one byte but remains a single piece of information. Even if only half of the data fit that description, and they managed to use just two bytes for all of those, that’s still a reduction of 25% – I think that it’s fair to call that “a whole lot smaller.”

Comment: @KRyan I frequently encode pieces of useful information in a single byte (usually amplitudes of some signal.) You can even get passable-quality audio with single-byte samples, even without compression. Not good quality, of course, but certainly enough to, for example, understand speech or listen to low-quality music. Also, as a slight nitpick, a byte has 256 distinct and meaningful possible values, not 255. 0 is meaningful, too.

Comment: @KRyan As you say, "piece of information" is *very* imprecise. It also is a term that works in an era where the general public is certainly *not* familiar with computers. And if we're going down that route, the AGC used 15-bit words (16 bits, if you count the parity bit), allowing for 32,768 discrete values per native machine word. Of course some ranges were in various ways "special". But that does not really seem to be related to this answer.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I was specifically responding to your claim “to the contrary” in response to user2617804; I don’t think your statement contradicts his at all.

Comment: @reirab Yes, so? Many things fit in one byte. Many things don’t.

Comment: @KRyan The point being that it's not only possible but common for well over a million "pieces of useful information" to fit in 8 MB, which does contradict user26179804's statement.

Comment: @reirab He didn’t say it was less than a million, or even less that “well over a million,” he said it was “a whole lot less” than eight million. There’s plenty of room there. But this discussion is pointless; I’ve obviously been unclear and now there’s three back-and-forths over a comment that was of only tenuous significance in the first place.

Comment: The original quote didn't specify RAM. The IBM 2314 disk storage facility was used with the IBM S/360 and held 233 megabytes, which gave you many millions of "pieces of information".